# Rendering Commerce Order

Tags: 7, commerce

API function commerce_order_build_content was deprecated, but I couldn't find one that was supposed to replace that. How do I drupal_render() a loaded commerce order? As of now, I'm getting "call to undefined function" commerce_order_build_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [entity_view](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!entity!entity.module/function/entity_view/DC):

```
$build = entity_view('commerce_order', $order, 'full');
$markup = drupal_render($build);
```

Comment: Very Helpful! I ended up using commerce_order_ui_order_view, which eventually calls entity_view.